# How to communicate data between iOS app and Django WebApp

Tags: sql, swift, django

So I am writing an IOS app that will present sort of a notification/message board. At the moment I have the board making a GET request to my django webapp for a JSON file that populates the messageboard.

My question is, how should I got about having a live feed to my notifications board? Such that once my webapp has created a "task" my ios app will populate that app as soon as possible, rather than waiting until the next time I open the app.

Comment: A tutorial would be better suited to help you with this question. This site is for answering more specific questions; yours is too broad to be considered appropriate.

Comment: You might want to check out Apple's documentation on [push notifications](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/fileprovider/content_and_change_tracking/tracking_your_file_provider_s_changes/using_push_notifications_to_signal_changes). Or on [app background refresh](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_background/updating_your_app_with_background_app_refresh)

Answer (score -1):

Too broad but why not use something like Firebase as your backend that connects your web app and your iOS app?

Comment: I have come across this solution and I was wondering if that is even necessary if I am already running a SQL database on AWS which is open to my webapp at the moment